# What does “scratched himself in the mirror” mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

One day Freddie Mercury met Sid Vicious and then Freddie was telling about the meeting:

> He had all these marks on him, so I asked if he had scratched himself in the mirror, and he hated the fact that I could speak to him like that.

What did he mean? Is it about shaving? Or maybe it is about MSR (mirror self-recognition test)?

Note: The quote above is from the book "Freddie Mercury: His life in his own words". But I found the original interview and in fact he said this: "Make sure to scratch yourself in the mirror properly today because tomorrow you're gonna get something else"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not very clear. But it is certainly an insult.

There seem to be various versions of what Sid said to Freddie, and what Freddie replied.

Sid Vicious had various marks on the skin of his face. Freddie is suggesting that he put them there himself, to make himself look tougher.  The "something else" that Sid will get tomorrow is a real beating up (if he comes back and makes fun of Freddie again.)

In general, Freddie is making fun of the "vicious" character, and suggesting that it is fake, and a sham created by Sid by scratching his own face.